# How do I upgrade to the latest version

Tags: upgrade, php

I'm a neophyte user trying to set my system up to program in PhP via Ubuntu. I have a cd with version 12.10 and would like to know how to upgrade after install and install packages for PHP... I'm guessing is what I need to do .... -- sooo I see that my version is no longer supported, how do I get the latest version

Comment: This is not a 100% duplicate because he hasn't actually installed Ubuntu yet let alone tried to upgrade, he just has a CD containing 12.10 and is wondering how to proceed.  So, the better advice is: don't, just download a newer CD image and install from that.

Comment: *"how do I get the latest version"* [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) includes information on how to obtain (and install) a supported release of Ubuntu. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop gives easy links to download 14.04.2 LTS or 15.04. You should probably use one of those versions, but for others you can visit: http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

12.10 is very old and out of date - you'd need to upgrade at least 3 times in a row just to get to a version that's current enough to be supported.

Instead, you should [download a new CD image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/) and install from that.

It will get you to version 14.04 or 14.10 with a lot less downloading.